# PSQL - How to do select on combination of two columns?

Tags: postgresql, ibatis

I have a table with columns as follows:

```
User
   id integer;
   firstName varchar;
   lastName varchar;
   employee_id integer;
```

Now the data in the table would be something as follows:

```
User(1,"John","Dake",123)
User(2,"John","Daniel",124)
User(3,"Richard","Johnson",125)
User(4,"Peter","Federo",126)
User(5,"George","Daniel",127)
```

I need to implement a search on the combination of first name - last Name. So let's say the search query is "**John D**". Then the output should be the first two rows. Is it possible to write such query without creating a new view or table to get the output?

Comment: Obligatory but still important and relevant programmer education link, please read: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE firstName||' '||lastName LIKE '%John D%'
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/af0bf/1)